# Does electrons revolve around a Neutron Star similar to an atom?

Tags: black-holes, electrons, wavelength, neutron-stars, proton-decay

Is a neutron star's residual light come from the electrons similar to an atom? Is the stars gravity holding in the electrons similar to protons in atoms?

Is the light we see from a neutron star not from fusion but from the electrons squeezed out by the gravity as it collapses eventually turning from blue to red then dark turning into a black hole with no singularity?

[image]

Comment: *"difference is gravity hold in the electrons instead of protons"* - gravity doesn't "hold in a proton" in an atom; *"last bit of light squeezed out by gravity"* - gravity doesn't "squeeze light out" ...you're not making any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is a neutron star's residual light released similar to an exited atom the difference is gravity hold in the electrons instead of protons?

No. Atomic energies are of order of keV at most,  the electrons are bound in  [energy levels](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hyde.html#c2) about the atom. There will only be photons produced if an electron is kicked to a higher energy level and then decays back down.

The gravity of a neutron star does not create energy levels for the electrons or  the protons/positive_ions (which must still exist for the star to be neutral in charge) at [its outer level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Neutron_star_cross_section.svg). The light/photons will be created by the acceleration of the charged particles in the magnetic field of the star and by scattering with each other.

> Is the light we see from it not from fusion but from the electrons in the star giving off the last bit of light squeezed out by gravity eventually going dark turning into a black hole with no singularity?

A [neutron star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star)  is not a black hole. The scatterings described above will be happening as the vacuum  around it  still has particles that can be trapped and interact while falling releasing photons but  considering that the temperature of neutron stars is of order of 10^9K, and 1 K corresponds to average kinetic energy of 8.6*10^-5 eV, there is enough kinetic energy for the neutron star to shine from black body radiation , after all.

Comment: I like both answers and I give my vote to the person with less rep, but if I could check mark both I would, unless you find fault in the lower rep user's answer then I will retract..

Comment: Further, the main transitions that contribute to the photon emission from the photosphere (not the magnetosphere, though this is negligible except in the brief pulsar phase) are atomic (or at least ionic) with transitions of *keV* downwards. eV only applies to outer shell optical transitions.

Comment: Where did you take that neutrons have electric dipole moments? According to your link, no neutron EDM has been found so far. Did you mean magnetic moments instead?

Comment: @Ruslan my bad , you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is interesting to calculate the radiation frequency for an electron in low orbit about a neutron star. The orbital frequency depends only on the density of the star or planet (radius doesn't matter!). Wikipedia tells me a neutron star has a density of 10^17 times as great as earth. The frequency goes as the square root of the density. The orbital period for an earth satellite is about 80 minutes (5000 seconds). This is a frequency of 200 microHertz. So for the neutron star, we multiply by almost 10^9, which gives us a frequency of 200 kHz...well, a little lower maybe...probably 60 kHz would be right.

At that frequency, wavelength of light is about 5 km. So for a reasonable size of neutron star (10 km) the electron would be traveling faster than the speed of light. I don't know how to correct this calculation for relativity. In any case, it's not a stationary state like you get for an atom...it's an accelerating trajectory that radiates, and hence decays.

Unless you're one of those people who believes that a charge doesn't radiate when it's accelerated by a gravitational field.

Comment: The mean density of a neutron star is 14 orders of magnitude greater than the Earth. The frequency you are looking for is below a kHz, corresponding to "millisecond pulsars". And the surface travels (of course) at less than c.

Comment: Calculating the classical radiation of an orbiting electron has nothing to do at all with an excited atom.

Comment: @rob jeffries yes you are right, I misread the density on Wikipedia. That brings my frequency down to 2 kHz which is in your ballpark; and of course also brings the speed down below c.

Comment: But if this really is the mechanism for your "millisecond pulsar", doesn't this answer in the affirmative the question of whether a charge radiates when accelerated by gravity? I thought that was still an open question.

Comment: Millisecond pulsars radiate by accelerating charges in a magnetic field. The pulsar radiation is seen over a very broad range of frequencies from radio to X-ray. Nothing to do with accelerating in gravitational fields unless you are talking about the inevitable redshift that the photons experience.